# Detecting Squares using pixels

Tags: sql, postgresql, graphics, relational-algebra

Well here is an interesting problem. Suppose I have a table on an sql db filled with x,y coordinates (positive quadrant) and each having a color value i.e. the schema looks like `<x , y, color>`. The task is to detect the largest possible square with the same color. Ive been trying to solve this problem for hours and cant seem to make a dent in it.

I'm not looking for a solution but rather hints.

Note that this all has to happen in SQL mainly using various joins, grouping and aggregate operations. Some sample code would be nice.

Comment: square perimeter or filled square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only request the corners be the same color, you could do

```
top left corner
join top right corner on equal x and color and greater y
join bottom left corner on equal y and color and greater x
join bottom right on equal x, y and color
order by (x1-x2)*(y1-x2) descending
limit 1
```

Of course, the limit 1 won`t have much effect on performance because it will have to generate all squares anyways.

You can (greatly) improve the speed by adding the (color,x,y) and (color,y,x) indexes.
The execution plan will most likely end up:

```
(1) full scan for all top left corners
(2) dependent index scan for all top right corners
(3) dependent index scan for all bottom left corners
(4) dependent index scan for the bottom right corner expecting at most one match
(5) (partial) table sort of the entire set of squares (cannot use indexes)
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks a lot! You just saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your problem space is small, let's say 10x10 (x bounded between 1 and 10), then a naive and brutal approach:

1. BotLeft: CROSS JOIN two sets of 10 numbers (say subset of a `Numbers` table) to give you bottom left corner of all possible squares (100 points)
2. TopRight: CROSS JOIN the same two sets to get all the points again
3. Squares: INNER JOIN between the two, filtered by where BotLeft must be to the left and below TopRight
4. Given all the possible squares, test each one by finally joining to your data where the (x,y) coordinates falls within the bounds of the square, e.g. `left <= x <= right`.  This generates a huge set
5. Collapse the previous set using GROUP BY (bottom-left,top-right) and test for distinct colors within the grouped subset, e.g. `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT color) = 1`.
6. If your dataset is not completely filled, then you also need to test that the `COUNT` of pixels in each square = count of data points found

Comment: Isn't a.color=b.color AND ... better than COUNT DISTINCT in terms of speed?

Comment: Yes, you could roll that optimisation into step 4, collecting only like colors. I did say it's a naive approach. I have no doubt it'll work and show the logic, but I'm also sure it's not the fastest method. You could even introduce color matching as early as step 2 if you really wanted.